# Where are the "physical files" created in a git branch?

Tags: git, github

First, I made App1 folder, initialized local repo, added remote repo and pushed to it:

```
mkdir App1
git init
git remote add <remote_repo_url>
git push origin master
```

Then, I created a branch, checked out to the branch, created a file there, then committed:

```
git branch "firstbranch"
git checkout firstbranch
touch file1.js
git add file1.js
git commit -m "added file1.js"
```

Now, I thought because although I am in firstbranch, I am still working in the same local workspace so:

1.) file1.js should appear in App1 folder

2.) If I checkout back to master and check git status, I should see file1.js as an untracked file.

But what actually happened is that file1.js isn't in App1 folder, and when I checkout back to master branch and checked git status, there is no remark about file1.js at all. But if I checkout to firstbranch and ls, file1.js is listed! Also, when I go to .git/branches, it is empty although I expected some data about firstbranch should be there. Can someone explain to me what's going on here? Where actually is file1.js and data about first branch?

Comment: `file1.js` was only committed to `firstbranch`. It does not exist on `master`. That means when you checkout `master`, you won't see files from other branches.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any files.  <insert record scratch noise here>  Wait, what?  Surely there are files.

Well, sort of.  The trick here is that Git stores *commits*.  That's your basic unit of storage: you either have a commit (they are numbered, by hash IDs), or you don't have that commit at all.

Each commit stores two things:

- The data in a commit is a full snapshot of *every* file that Git knows about.
- The metadata in a commit remembers the name and email address of the person who made the commit, and so on.

So in a sense, the commit contains the files.  But they're not stored as *files*, exactly.  They're stored as Git *objects*, specifically *blob objects*, which hold the files' contents, but—notably—*not* their names.  These blob objects have hash IDs (in the same way that commits have hash IDs).  All Git objects are physically stored in `.git/objects/`, but there are two storage formats as well:

- *Loose* objects are stored in individual files.  Loose here is the opposite of packed.
- *Packed* objects are stored with many objects in a single *pack file*.

(The files' *names* are stored separately, in *tree* objects, which are linked to the commits, which are stored in *commit* objects.  There is a fourth type of object, the *annotated tag* object, that is used for annotated tags, and those four objects make up the entire object database: all of everything ever committed.)

> Now, I thought because although I am in firstbranch, I am still working in the same local workspace ...

This is a wrong way to view a repository: it will mislead you.

The right way to view a repository is this:

- There is a collection of internal Git objects, in formats you don't really need to care about very much, but it's worth knowing that each object is entirely read-only, and is stored in a compressed and Git-only format.  The loose objects are pretty easy to read in many languages as they're merely zlib-compressed with a header, but the packed ones are much trickier.  Still, Git reserves the right to change the internal storage system in the future, so it's best to just let Git read them for you.
- There is a thing that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  We won't go into every detail here—in particular we'll ignore merges—but it's vitally important that you understand what this does for you, when you go about making new commits.
- Finally, in most repositories—the ones you will do work in, at least—there is a *working tree* or *work-tree*.  (Git mostly calls it a working tree, but I like the shorter term.)

Given that the files inside a commit are in a compressed, frozen and de-duplicated, Git-only format, the need for this work-tree is clear enough: you need to have access to your files as *ordinary* files, that you can read *and* write.  So Git will *extract* the files from a commit to your work-tree.

The index itself is a bit complicated—it takes on a bigger role during conflicted merges, for instance—but it's *how* Git knows about you files, and a good one-line summary of Git's index is this: **The index holds all the files that will go into the *next* commit you will make.**

When you check out some commit, Git:

1. copies—using the frozen and de-duplicated format, so there's no actual *copy* here—each file that is *in* that commit into Git's index;
2. expands that file into your work-tree.

In this way, Git's index now matches the commit you've checked out, *and* you have your files visible to you, in ordinary read/write format.  Your work-tree is now *yours*, to do with as you will.  You can create, remove, read, and write your files.  You can do anything that your computer can do with these work-tree files, because they are *yours*.

The files that Git *knows about*, though, are still there in Git's index, in the frozen format, ready to go into a new commit:

- If you *change* a file in your work-tree in some way, you must tell Git: *Copy this updated file back into your index.*  That way, Git will know about the updated file.
- If you remove a file, you should remove it from both your work-tree and Git's index.  (The `git rm` command will do this, for instance.)  Now that it's not in Git's index, it won't be in the next commit.
- If you create an all-new file, and want it to be in the *next* commit, you should have Git add it.

The `git add` command actually handles all three of these cases, because it tells Git: *Make the index copy match the work-tree copy.*  If you've removed the work-tree copy, `git add` *removes* the index copy to match.  If you've updated the work-tree copy, or if the work-tree copy of that file—by that name—isn't in the index at all, `git add` actually turns the file into the special frozen-and-compressed format at this time, and updates or creates the index copy as appropriate.

In other words, whatever you did in your work-tree, `git add` will make Git's index reflect this change, or these changes, by making Git's index match your work-tree.  So the index will now have the *next* commit ready to go.

Remember, the index started out matching the current commit.  The *current commit*, the one you picked with `git checkout` or `git switch`, has a snapshot of files in it, in a frozen, compressed, and de-duplicated format.  Git's index initially held all those same files, in the same format: it matched the commit.  Your work-tree initially held those same files as well, but in a usable format.

By modifying your work-tree, you changed things so that the commit copies and index copies still matched, but your work-tree didn't.  By updating the index—which holds files in the frozen *format*, but lets you *replace* them, which commits can't do—you've changed things so that the commit copies *don't* match the index copies any more, but now the index and work-tree copies match.

If you run `git commit` *now*, the *new* commit will match Git's index, which matches your work-tree, and you'll be back in that happy state in which all your work-tree files are permanently saved in the current commit.  Note that the new commit *becomes* the current commit when `git commit` succeeds.

Now, suppose you are in this happy state—all three copies of each file match—and you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to *switch* to some *other* commit.  Git will:

- remove all the index copies that go with *this* commit, replacing them with index copies that go with the new commit you want to use; and
- at the same time, remove all the work-tree copies that go with *this* commit, replacing them with unfrozen, expanded-out, de-Git-ified plain files that go with the new commit you want to use.

That new commit *becomes* your current commit, and once again, you are in this happy state in which all three copies of every file match.

But: if the commit you pick to switch *to* has a different set of *file names* and/or *file contents* than the commit you switched *from*, well, now Git has *replaced* your work-tree with one that matches the commit you've just switched *to*.

**Note that Git didn't care about which *branch name* you are using.  Git cares, instead, about which *commit* you are using.**  A branch name is useful—especially to humans, because we are terrible at remembering those random-looking hash IDs—but it just serves as a way to *find* a commit's *number*.  The branch name holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.

When you make a new commit, Git packages up whatever files are in the index *right then*, adds the appropriate metadata, and writes that out as your new commit.  This new commit gets a new, unique number: a new hash ID.  Then Git puts this hash ID into the *current branch name*, which is how the branch now has a new commit in it.  This means that the *name itself* now holds a different hash ID than it did a moment ago.

To make all of this make sense, it may help if you *draw* your commits.  Use something, like uppercase letters for instance, to stand in for the real hash IDs.  Draw the commits like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

The *branch name* `master` holds the real hash ID of commit we're calling `H`.  Commit `H` itself has, in its metadata, the real hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Commit `G` has `F`'s hash ID in `G`'s metadata.  So by using the *name* `master`, we can have Git find commit `H`, from which Git can find commit `G`, and then `F`, and so on.

In other words, Git works *backwards*.  A branch name just holds the hash ID of the *last* commit.  It's now easier to see how new commits work.  Let's make a new branch name, `feature`, that *also contains `H`'s hash ID*, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature, master
```

Let's add the word `(HEAD)` after `feature` to indicate that we did `git checkout feature` or `git switch feature` to pick commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), master
```

Commit `H` is now our current commit, and is in Git's index and our work-tree.  We change some files—and maybe even add and/or remove some files—and use `git add` to update Git's index to match.  Then we run `git commit`.

Git packages up whatever is in the index *right then*, which is what is in our work-tree because we used `git add` correctly.  Git adds the appropriate metadata for commit `I`: our name, the current date and time, a log message we give Git, and—to make the backwards stuff work—the hash ID of existing commit `H`, so that new commit `I` points backwards to `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), master
            \
             I
```

Now that commit `I` exists (and has its new hash ID), Git writes that hash ID into the *name* to which `HEAD` is attached, so that `feature` points to new commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

If we `git checkout master`, Git will switch to commit `H`, and attach `HEAD` to the name `master`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I   <-- feature
```

Our current commit is now `H`, not `I`, and our work-tree will match commit `H`, not commit `I`.  If we make another new commit *now*, the name `master` will be the one that gets updated:

```
...--F--G--H--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I   <-- feature
```

This is how branches work.  Git is all about the *commits;* the branch names serve to let us (and Git) *find* the commit hash IDs.  The *files* we see and work with, in our work-tree, are not the files in Git at all.  Git stores entire commits—full snapshots of *every* file, as they appeared in Git's index at the time we ran `git commit`—in a special Git-only format.  We pick a commit to work with, and Git extracts that commit to our work-tree.

Answer (score 0):

The file file1.js will remain in the `firstbranch` branch until you make a PR to your `master` branch and merge it, you can have a look on this [link](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) I hope it can help you.
[image]

Note: [Github Documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)

Comment: This is also very good: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects