# what order should i follow for git commands

Tags: git, github

i m new to git and not sure of what order shall i use for the following git commands
suppose i m in master branch now. i want to do some changes. but not in master branch. I intend to make those changes in a new branch. shall i checkout to a new branch first and do the changes. (or) make the changes and checkout before pushing the changes..

```
>>>master branch
   git add .
   git commit -m "fixing Failures"
   git checkout -b fixing_feature1_Testcases
   git push --set-upstream origin fixing_feature1_Testcases
```

OR

```
>>>master branch
   git checkout -b fixing_feature1_Testcases

>>>fixing_feature1_Testcases branch #(switched to new branch)
   git add .
   git commit -m "fixing Failures"
   git push
```

Comment: See [my answer to this question about Git storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63360791/1256452).

Comment: Try to edit and write more carefully what you are trying to achieve, and how you intend to use git. Are you using it for a project where you are the only contributor? In a small team? Large/enterprise team? If you have an example of the intended result, describe it. Also, try to capitalize First word in sentences, break up test into paragraphs, whatever makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the commit in `master` : do the second version.